# How to make less show the previous lines when searching?

Tags: less

How can I make `less` show the previous couple of lines when I search for something? I'd like to get rid of the `kkk` steps in my usual process:

- `/keyword`
- `kkk`
- (read)
- `n`
- `kkk`
- (read)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ less -j 4 file
```

That will put the pattern you searched for on line 4 of the terminal.

To save typing this every time, you can put `LESS=j4` into your environment.